# Android NsdServiceInfo setAttribute update after register

Tags: android, setattribute, nsd

After initially setting up attributes for the NsdServiceInfo and calling registerService, how is it possible to update the attributes?

With iOS, you just call [service setTXTRecordData...].  I don't see any way to do it with Android so far.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with iOS API, but I don't think there is a direct way to do this with NSD API, according to [rfc 6762 section 8.4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6762#section-8.4):

> At any time, if the rdata of any of a host's Multicast DNS records
> changes, the host MUST repeat the Announcing step described above to
> update neighboring caches. For example, if any of a host's IP
> addresses change, it MUST re-announce those address records. The
> host does not need to repeat the Probing step because it has already
> established unique ownership of that name.
>
> In the case of shared records, a host MUST send a "goodbye"
> announcement with RR TTL zero (see Section 10.1, "Goodbye Packets")
> for the old rdata, to cause it to be deleted from peer caches, before
> announcing the new rdata.  In the case of unique records, a host
> SHOULD omit the "goodbye" announcement, since the cache-flush bit on
> the newly announced records will cause old rdata to be flushed from
> peer caches anyway.

Attributes are usually advertised in TXT record, So I don't think iOS has some magic to update the TXT record, it must re-announce or send a "goodbye" announcement. Since Android NSD doesn't provide an API to send a single TXT record, AFAIK, the only way to do this is to call `NsdManager.unregisterService()` then `NsdManager.registerService()`.

Comment: yeah, that's really messy. I tried that.  that causes the record to disappear and then reappear. any observing app will tear down everything for the record and then have to re-add it when it appears.  with iOS, calling the setTXTRecordData method just instantly causes the attributes to show up in the observing clients.

Answer (score 0):

I know everyone hates that type of answers...

But consider trying 3rd party lib for doing that.
E.g. JmDNS: https://github.com/jmdns/jmdns

Pros:

- it doesn't have issues on pre-Marshmallow (built-in Android NSD is very buggy on pre-M, e.g. you can't read attributes of the discovered service);
- you can update registered service attributes using the setText() method of ServiceInfo object.

Cons:

- it doesn't work if Android device is used as a hotspot (has no Internet access and provides its own WiFi access point without Internet access).

Comment: I used to use JMDNS, but switched to NSD a year or so ago.  I'll switch back and try that.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW the native bonjour API supports updating txt records w/o unregistering the service.

From dns_sd.h

```
DNSServiceUpdateRecord
 *
 * Update a registered resource record. The record must either be:
 *   - The primary txt record of a service registered via DNSServiceRegister()
 *   - A record added to a registered service via DNSServiceAddRecord()
 *   - An individual record registered by DNSServiceRegisterRecord()
```